# Fixed Nav changing Opacity depending on background

Tags: html, css

http://www.kieran-smith.co.uk/

Hi,

Hope I'm able to explain this properly.
On the above website you should see a fixed Nav with a light grey background.
If you scroll the background opacity seems to change but I'm not sure why, each background image has an opacity of 0.7 however this is set within the separate div not on the nav.

https://jsfiddle.net/2aLwazks/

```
.kimg1, .kimg2, .kimg3 {
position:relative;
opacity:0.70;
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}

.kimg1 {
    background-image:url("http://www.kieran-smith.co.uk/img/image1.png");
    min-height:100%;
}

.top-menu {
position:fixed;
top:0;
background:#dddddd;
color:#444444;
width:100%;
padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the form of a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of a link to an external site, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by the question you are wanting the nav to not change color, so to fix that just add  z-index: 10; to the .top-menu so it would look like this

```
.top-menu {
position:fixed;
top:0;
background:#dddddd;
color:#444444;
width:100%;
padding:10px;
z-index: 10;
```

}

Comment: Yep, can't believe I forgot about z-index!

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
 margin:0;
 font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
 height:100%;
 font-size:16px;
 line-height:1.8em;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#666;
}

.kimg1, .kimg2, .kimg3 {
 position:relative;
 opacity:0.70;
 background-position:center;
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment:fixed;
}

.kimg1 {
 background-image:url("http://www.kieran-smith.co.uk/img/image1.png");
 min-height:100%;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-size:contain;
}

.kimg2 {
 background-image:url("http://www.kieran-smith.co.uk/img/image1.png");
 min-height:400px;
}

.kimg3 {
 background-image:url("http://www.kieran-smith.co.uk/img/image1.png");
 min-height:400px;
}

.section {
 text-align:center;
 padding:50px 80px;
}

.section-light {
 background:#f4f4f4;
 color:#666;
}

.section-dark {
 background-color:#282e34;
 color:#ddd;
}

.ktext {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 color:#111;
 font-size:27px;
 letter-spacing:8px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.ktext .border {
 background-color:#111;
 color:#fff;
 padding:20px;
}

.ktext .border.trans {
 background-color:transparent;
}

.top-menu {
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 background:rgba(221,221,221, 0.8);
 color:#444444;
 width:100%;
 padding:10px;
  z-index:1000;
}

@media(max-width:568px) {
 .kimg1, .kimg2, .kimg3 {
  background-attachment:scroll;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
 <nav class="top-menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="">Page One</a>
    <a href="">Page Two</a>
    <a href="">Page Three</a>
 </nav>

   <div class="kimg1">
    <div class="ktext">
     <span class="border">
    Kieran Smith
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>

   <section class="section section-light">
    <h2>Section One</h2>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem labore ex, eius doloribus. Omnis maxime illum ad dolorem. Numquam qui autem vitae quibusdam fugit distinctio quam labore sapiente at doloribus eos neque quisquam dicta incidunt, mollitia itaque quaerat facere, maxime nihil quae totam enim quidem iure tempora inventore? Aperiam facere veritatis porro quas nostrum laborum doloremque autem, error in temporibus exercitationem nesciunt animi illum voluptatibus ipsa ducimus adipisci fugit repellendus, ut nemo blanditiis commodi eos tenetur molestias? Ipsa consectetur laudantium quibusdam cum, nesciunt ducimus saepe soluta unde nihil sunt neque, aspernatur officia necessitatibus delectus eius qui ut a iusto velit?
  </p>
   </section>

   <div class="kimg2">
    <div class="ktext">
     <span class="border trans">
    Image Two Text
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>


   <section class="section section-dark">
    <h2>Section Two</h2>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem labore ex, eius doloribus. Omnis maxime illum ad dolorem. Numquam qui autem vitae quibusdam fugit distinctio quam labore sapiente at doloribus eos neque quisquam dicta incidunt, mollitia itaque quaerat facere, maxime nihil quae totam enim quidem iure tempora inventore? Aperiam facere veritatis porro quas nostrum laborum doloremque autem, error in temporibus exercitationem nesciunt animi illum voluptatibus ipsa ducimus adipisci fugit repellendus, ut nemo blanditiis commodi eos tenetur molestias? Ipsa consectetur laudantium quibusdam cum, nesciunt ducimus saepe soluta unde nihil sunt neque, aspernatur officia necessitatibus delectus eius qui ut a iusto velit?
  </p>
   </section>


   <div class="kimg3">
    <div class="ktext">
     <span class="border trans">
    Image Three Text
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>

   <section class="section section-dark">
    <h2>Section Three</h2>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem labore ex, eius doloribus. Omnis maxime illum ad dolorem. Numquam qui autem vitae quibusdam fugit distinctio quam labore sapiente at doloribus eos neque quisquam dicta incidunt, mollitia itaque quaerat facere, maxime nihil quae totam enim quidem iure tempora inventore? Aperiam facere veritatis porro quas nostrum laborum doloremque autem, error in temporibus exercitationem nesciunt animi illum voluptatibus ipsa ducimus adipisci fugit repellendus, ut nemo blanditiis commodi eos tenetur molestias? Ipsa consectetur laudantium quibusdam cum, nesciunt ducimus saepe soluta unde nihil sunt neque, aspernatur officia necessitatibus delectus eius qui ut a iusto velit?
  </p>
   </section>


   <div class="kimg1">
    <div class="ktext">
     <span class="border">
    Kieran Smith
     </span>
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

I changed your Css Menu top-menu Class to

```
.top-menu {
position:fixed;
top:0;
background:rgba(221,221,221, 0.8);
color:#444444;
width:100%;
padding:10px;
z-index:1000;
}
```

also updated your [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2aLwazks/1/)

Is that what you want?